# Handler not executing run method as per minute specify?

Tags: android, handler, interstitial

I am showing Interstitial ads after 1 minute i am using handler for that
It works properly for few minutes after that its showing ads before 1 minute completing its showing rapidly after five seconds 10 seconds  like wise
how to solve this issue.

here is my code

prepareAd();

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");
                    }

                    prepareAd();




                }
            });

        }
    }, 60, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


public void prepareAd(){

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


}
```

Comment: Paste your code as well.

Comment: I m suggest you please don't do like this way Google will disabled your ads.

Comment: Handler handler1 = new Handler();
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                show_Insertisial();

            }
        },60000);

Comment: Depending on how you set up your handler, you may have multiple loops running, executing more than once a minute.

Comment: add your code to the question not in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is against AdMob policy and your account will get suspended if you do so.

If you want to learn more stuffs about how to place admob ad in your application. I recommend you to visit this website.

http://www.elegantespace.com/how-to-load-interstitial-ad-at-regular-interval-of-time/

Comment: Please quote the important code in your answer as the linked site may go down.

Comment: Hi i used http://www.elegantespace.com/how-to-load-interstitial-ad-at-regular-interval-of-time/ code but issue is still there